# Debian ARM Qt Creator G++ compiler

Tags: qt, g++, arm, debian, beagleboneblack

As I have no time for configuring arm g++ cross compiler on my i686 debian machine, I decided to install graphic mode on my BeagleBone which runs on Debian. Does arm g++ compiler exists for debian BBB distribution? I just wanted to skip cross-compiling and build my code on BBB, and run it immediately after it is compiled. I'm looking for answers if that is possible, or cross-compiling is necessary thing in this situation?

Comment: Regardless of the fact that it exists or not, compiling on a BeagleBone Black will be quite slow compared to on your PC. Not to mention the IDE will also be slower...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are g++ compilers for the following architectures:

> amd64 arm64 **armel armhf** i386 mips mipsel powerpc ppc64el s390x

See https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=g%2B%2B. If you are running plain `arm` and the two highlighted architectures don't fit the bill, you're out of luck.